# Healthkit plugin in Meteor

Tags: cordova, meteor, plugins, healthkit

I am trying to get steps count using Healthkit in meteor, i have added the cordova healthkit plugin using command *meteor add cordova:com.telerik.plugins.healthkit@0.3.5* and addded healthkit in entitlements in IOS build, but when i am checking for window.plugins.healthkit or navigator.plugins.healthkit it returns false.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you enabled health kit in capabilities tab in Xcode?

Comment: yes, i got the hack. It was cordova-ios issue, i have to manually add the plugin in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was unable to find Plugin_name.m file in the plugins directory as well, so i manually added the Plugin_name.m file in build phases (you can find Plugin_name.m file in plugin->src->ios folder) and then copy the feature name of plugin from ios.json file (which is present in cordova-builds folder) and add it to config.xml file(remove back-slashes).
Plugin will work fine.

Note:- You may have to add all the files in build phases which is included in plugin_name.m file.